# Integrating Function with Modulo

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, modular-arithmetic

Is there a particular method that is used to evaluate integrals that involve modulo arithmetic? For example;

$$\int_0^t x\sin(x)\, (\mathrm{mod \ 2}) dx$$

The problem that I am trying to solve is
$$\int_0^t -\frac{1}{2}+((s+\pi\omega s)\, (\mathrm{mod \ 1}))\, ds$$
When plotted, I was thinking you could break this up into piecewise functions. But this would be really inefficient. Is there a way that this can be solved? Or is it not possible? Also in the above, $\omega$ is simply a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto x (\mod 1)$ (or $x\mapsto x - \lfloor x \rfloor]$) is a *sawtooth* function. If you want to avoid using piecewise functions you could replace it with its Fourier series:

$$g\left(x\right)\ =\frac{1}{2}-\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(2\cdot\pi\cdot k\cdot\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{\pi}$$

Comment: so for this example could I consider $\int_0^t -\frac{1}{2}+g(s)+\pi\omega g(s)\, ds$?

Comment: If I read your parenthesis right I think it should be $\int_0^t -1/2 + g(s+\pi \omega s)ds$ (=$\int_0^t -1/2 + g(s\cdot (1+\pi \omega))ds$)